# Can i update a customfield in WHMCS with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, whmcs

I've tried using
https://www.npmjs.com/package/whmcs

But the function to update the customer details is not explained so good, or maybe because i'm new to programming. The function i'm trying to use is:

updateCustomer: function (clientid, options, callback)

I'm not sure on how to fill the values, clientid i've figured out and made a variable for that.

Please help.. I want to learn this